# How to create a sparkline / single-cell chart that shows status color changes over time

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm re-creating some reports that track the status of various projects over their lifecycle. Internally, we define the status of each project as Red, Amber (Yellow) or Green, and then these values are updated weekly.

I'd like to represent this in the summary report with a sparkline (or similar) for each project so that at a glance the reader can see how the project has progressed.

My mental image is of something where a cell is divided into a number of sections vertically, with each one representing one weekly update in the project's life, and that section of the cell being colored to match the status of the project at that point in time.

Is this (or something similar) possible?

EDIT: At the suggestion of the comment below, here is an example of what I'm thinking of:

1. If a range of data contains the data `['Green', 'Yellow', 'Green']`, the resultant cell would look like this:

   [image: example 1]
2. If the range of data has the values `['Green', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Green', 'Green', 'Red', 'Green']`, the resultant cell would look like this:

   [image: example 2]

   Note that these are within one cell - the idea is that these would resize those colored sections to match the number of values in the range.

**EDIT 2:** A full sample of what I expect the eventual table would look like:

| Name | Wk 1 | Wk 2 | Wk 3 | Wk 4 | Wk 5 | Wk 6 | Wk 7 | Wk 8 | Wk 9 | Wk 10 | Chart |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Green | Yellow | Green | [image: example 3] |
| Project2 | Green | Yellow | Green | Green | Yellow | Yellow | Red | Green | Green | Red | [image: example 4] |

Note: The colors shown here are simply text entered into each cell by the user.

Comment: Almost anything is possible in Excel-how complicated/difficult it is to implement tends to be the limiting factor.  It would help to have a visual of what you're looking for and what your data looks like.

Comment: @dav - thanks for that, I've added some example screenshots of the kind of thing I have in mind

Comment: @dav ,,, better [edit] your post & share some sample data that how you are determining the colors ,,,, will help me & others to suggest solution !!

Comment: @RajeshSinha - Thanks, I've added another complete example of what I have in mind.

Comment: @DTR let me remind U that any chart only considers NUMBERS or numeric data,,, what U are trying needs something different. You may either create a Progress Bar or Stacked Bar using Cell values then U may pick colors accordingly,, as far my experience VBA is another option for Colors automation !!

Comment: @RajeshSinha In that case, would it not be possible to have a hidden row below each entry that with a formula like `=SWITCH(A1, "Green", 1, "Yellow", 2, "Red", 3, "")` or similar, and then generate the same chart from that? My main concern is getting the output looking that way, not how the data is presented (as this can be altered as required).

Comment: @DTR let me give one simple example,,, In col A put Some Numbers & in Col for Adjacent cells apply some formula like if(A1<=50 ,"Green","") ,, and also apply Conditional formatting on Col B cells accordingly then create Stacked Column chart and finally use VBA macro to put colors as per cell colors !